# Google fit padometer

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to use google fit Activity detection function in my application .When my phone doesn't have google fit application Everything is working fine except the padometer part (Means the steps detection in background). And when i install google fit app in my phone and turn on activity detection the steps are counted and working fine .

So my question is in that way my application is gonna be google fit app dependent .If user don't have fit app installed my application won't show the sensor data(steps,activity name,distance etc). So correct me here How to deal with that problem .Because google fit application not came in all devices by default. So without google fit app how i can sense padometer data and activity name and distance etc..

Comment: You want the pedometer code?

Comment: thats what i am asking .. Do i need to create my own padometer for this

Comment: Yeah its better if you have your own code independent of google fit

Comment: Okay thx .. Well i guess i have to stand on my own then .In that way google fit is like waste for me ..

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to step detection algo in https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer. To make your results more accurate, whatever values you get from this algo is not stable, so store it in a list say 10 values and for every 10 values, find 2 minimum and 2 maximum of it. Eliminate them and for remaining 6 values, calculate the average and this would give you a better result.

Comment: Hey Thanks man .. I just downloaded it .. Lets see If it worked . Get back to you about result..

Comment: Can we use Gogle fit sdk's SensorApi for pedometer purpose ?

Comment: Why is this upvoted? The library is 6 years old, according to the answer, it is highly erroneous.

Comment: For the information guys we can use Google fit to count steps for our application Using RecordingApi.